# OST-file 5x as large as mailbox?

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2003

I've got an issue with a user whose Outlook runs really slow. Her Exchange mailbox is ~4.6 Gb, which while large should be alright (she's got a 3.2 GHz i5 with 4 Gb RAM)? However, the .ost-file is 20.2 Gb. Why is it so much larger? I've run scanpst/scanost, which reported it repaired a few errors, but the size didn't shrink.

I've turned off Cached mode since it was causing thousands of conflict-copies, which was also filling up this user's mailbox.

Any suggestions on what to do? We're running Outlook 2007 on Windows 7, connected to Exchange 2003 on SBS 2003.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OST will not shrink by moving the files. You will need to compact them.  Right-click on the OST, Properties, Advanced, Compact Now.

Comment: +1. Or, if she's got a couple of hours, simply delete (or rename) the ost and let it re-sync from the server.